# How to get my tomcat app statistic on new relic

Tags: java, tomcat, newrelic

I have a java application running on tomcat. This app reads requests from rabbit-mq and based on the operation type in the request message performs/calls certain class to complete the operation. And pushes back the response into rabbit-mq.

There is no end point to this app which is called directly.

New Relic tracks the endpoints being called. In my app there is no end-point.

How can I make New Relic to track my requests based on the operation name and monitor it. Or is there any other way to monitor my app.

Answer (score 0):

if you use eclipse you can easy to monitor/trace your app. Add break point and Press Debug
[image]

Answer (score 0):

New Relic [supports RabbitMQ](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/agents/java-agent/getting-started/compatibility-requirements-java-agent#http-messaging) and should be able to track when a message is received.

It instruments any class that implements `com.rabbitmq.client.Consumer` adding code to the `handleDelivery(String, Envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties, byte[])` method.

It also change some other classes. All the changes are in the [rabbit-amqp instrumentation module](https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-java-agent/tree/main/instrumentation/rabbit-amqp-5.0.0/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/client).